# Control different flash projector on the same LAN

Tags: flash, projector

Does anyone know how to control a projector on a pc, from another projector on another pc, in the same LAN?
any solution is good for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually is possible and really easy to do with zinc, wich have a nice custom object called Network.

http://www.multidmedia.com/support/livedocs/index.php?url=class.php?action=class=Network

the user can also listen (connect) to some "server" type of application that could control them remotely (even if within LAN). The similar solutions (that is based on tcp/ip protocols) could be based on Flash runtime built-in supports for sockets connection (xml socket, raw sockets) and locally installed server similar to FoxServer/ElectroServer (or any other solution including open source solution).

*source: zinc forums*

Answer (score 0):

Control of projectors is quite easy using a PC, find a copy of "TCPLINE" by Davis Moshenkovs.
Write a batch file include the line "tcpline 192.168.100.100 7142 1000 H:"020000000002" to turn on an NEC projector.
Write a batch file include the line "tcpline 192.168.100.100 7142 1000 H:"020100000003" to turn off an NEC projector.
Just find the Extended rs232 files for the projector you want to control, set the static ip address in the projector to the ip address in the batch file, use the listening port number and insert the control code you want from the extended rs232 codes. Works using rs232 connection and lan connection.
For control of sanyo or eiki projectors I recommend using "TST10" by Albert Yale.
Write a batch file include the line "TST10.exe /r:FISHon.txt /m" you also need a text file called FISHon.txt the /m is (return key).
The Text file should contain 6 lines
192.168.100.100 10000
WAIT "PASSWORD:"
SEND "\m"
WAIT "Hello"
SEND "CF POWER ON\m"
WAIT "000"
Put them all in the same folder.